# Arbitrary filters for conv2d (as opposed to rectangular)

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I using convolutional layers on data samples that consist of 2d images. One option for the shape of the filter is 1x2, which acts on a 1x2 contiguous block of two neighbor pixels. What if I want to have a filter which also acts on 2 pixels, but the pixels are separated by another one between them? Is it possible to encode such a filter for convolutions in the neural network?

Comment: You can create a 'mask' of zeros and ones and then apply it to the weights and do a normal convolution?

Answer (score 7):

## Code to make it work

[You can also watch a video of how to make it work with Keras](https://youtu.be/pImJayaXmCM)

Here is some example code which defines a kernel for Conv2d and a 5x5 mask that only lets the center and outside values pass through.

```
image = np.array( range(25) ).reshape([1,5,5,1] ).astype( float )

kern = tf.Variable( tf.ones( [5,5,1,1] , dtype=tf.float32) )

mask = np.array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
                 [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  1],
                 [ 1,  0,  1,  0,  1],
                 [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  1],
                 [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1]]).reshape( [5,5,1,1] )

mask_variable = tf.constant( mask , dtype=tf.float32 )

output           = tf.nn.conv2d( image , kern        , strides=[1,1,1,1] , padding="VALID" )
output_with_mask = tf.nn.conv2d( image , kern * mask , strides=[1,1,1,1] , padding="VALID" )

print("Using whole kernal :",output.numpy())
print("Using kernal with a mask :",output_with_mask.numpy())
```

And the output

```
Using whole kernal : [[[[ 300.]]]]
Using kernal with a mask : [[[[ 204.]]]]
```

Furthermore, backprop will not change the mask because the mask is wrapped in tf.stop_gradient.

cheers

Comment: I'm experimenting with convolutional networks for a game on hexagonal grid. That seems to be a valid application of this technique.

Comment: That is a cool application and totally appropriate!  I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Why are the stop_gradient() operations necessary when they only act on constants?

Comment: I just saw that also.  It isn't necessary but would be if it was a variable.  I updated the code to show that you can use a tf.Variable and it works.

Comment: @Marc did you get far with your hexagonal stuff? I need that, appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Not as far as I'd hoped, but got it working. The code change was pretty straightforward from Panchishin's example.

Comment: I'm curious about this hex-based convolution.  @marc how can I find out more about what you were doing?  Is it a public project on github that I could take a look?

Comment: The project is not public, because it is for a programming contest, and I'd like to participate this year again. I'll put a code snippet in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but a code snippet to show how I used Panchishin's answer to code for a Hexagonal game (Moderators: if there's a better way to expand on a comment, or send a private message to someone, please let me know)

Caveat: I'm a beginner in deep learning.

The game is Blackhole, used in the 2018 CodeCup competition: http://archive.codecup.nl/2018/60/rules_blackhole.html
It is a hexagonal game played in a triangle shape. The code below defines the convolutional and relu layers.

```
def conv_weight_variable(w, h, in_ch, out_ch, learn):
    d = 1.0 / np.sqrt(in_ch * w * h)
    initial = tf.truncated_normal([w, h, in_ch, out_ch], stddev=d)
    return tf.Variable(initial, trainable=learn), iEnd

def conv_bias_variable(w, h, in_ch, out_ch, learn):
    d = 1.0 / np.sqrt(in_ch * w * h)
    initial = tf.constant([0.1*d]*out_ch, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.Variable(initial, trainable=learn), iEnd

def relu_conv_layer(input, in_ch, out_ch, learn):
    W, iEnd = conv_weight_variable(3, 3, in_ch, out_ch, learn)
    o = np.zeros((in_ch, out_ch), np.float32)
    i = np.ones((in_ch, out_ch), np.float32)
    maskW = np.array([[ o, i, i],
                      [ i, i, i],
                      [ i, i, o]])
    maskW = tf.constant(maskW, dtype=tf.float32)
    b, iEnd = conv_bias_variable(3, 3, in_ch, out_ch, learn)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, W * maskW, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    o = np.zeros(out_ch, np.float32)
    i = np.ones(out_ch, np.float32)
    maskO = np.array([[ i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i],
                      [ i, i, i, i, i, i, i, o],
                      [ i, i, i, i, i, i, o, o],
                      [ i, i, i, i, i, o, o, o],
                      [ i, i, i, i, o, o, o, o],
                      [ i, i, i, o, o, o, o, o],
                      [ i, i, o, o, o, o, o, o],
                      [ i, o, o, o, o, o, o, o]])
    maskO = tf.constant(maskO, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.nn.relu(conv + b)*maskO, W, b, iEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary filters (with weights placed anywhere) are not available, but there exists a limited by useful version called atrous convolution that places weights on a spare grid, which can handle your specific example.

For example, in your case, you could try

```python
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((1, 2, n_in, n_out))
tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(value, W, (1, 2), 'SAME')
```